# How can I have a public (global) variable assigned to the OnProperty of a SwitchCell (isOn binding) to check if a SwichCell is enabled (On)

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I want to have a SwitchCell within a ListView which is able to "remember" the state of the last SwitchCell event (Toggled) when the page is changed or the App closes and opens up again.

I have a class called **Relays** where I implemented the variables for binding to the SwitchCell properties of **On** and **Text**.

I am able to Bind the properties in the code behind RelayControl.xaml.cs class but I want to have a variable (or equivalent) to analyze/check the **On** state of the SwitchCell when the Page is opened.

I know the solution *might* be simple but I am very new to Xamarin and C# and I have been reading the Data Binding Basics on the Microsoft [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics) (among other sources) and I can't seem to relate them to my current problem. Any help/examples/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

My Relays.cs class is as follows:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Text;

 namespace Socket.Models
 {
     public class Relays
     {
         public Boolean isOn { get; set; }       // Set the state of 
                                                    the switch 

         public string State { get; set; }       // Get the state of 
                                 the switch based on the isOn property

         public string Name { get; set; }        // Set the name of the 
                                                 relay in the list

     }
 }
```

The RelayControl.xaml is as follows:

```
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Socket.RelayControl"
         Title="Relay Control Page">

  <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Padding="10,0,0,0">

        <ListView x:Name="lstView" SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <SwitchCell x:Name="Sw1" Text="{Binding Name, 
                     Mode=TwoWay}" On="{Binding isOn, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                OnChanged="OnChanged_2"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
          </ListView>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

the RelayControl.xaml.cs is as follows:

```
 using Socket.Models;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using Xamarin.Forms;
 using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

 namespace Socket
 {
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]

public partial class RelayControl : ContentPage
{
    public RelayControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        loadSampleData();

    }

    private void loadSampleData()
    {
        // Create sample data


        ObservableCollection<Relays> listRelays = new 
         ObservableCollection<Relays>();

        listRelays.Add(new Relays { Name ="Relay 1", State = "", 
                                   isOn=false });
        listRelays.Add(new Relays { Name ="Relay 2", State = "", 
                                   isOn=false });
        listRelays.Add(new Relays { Name ="Relay 3", State = "", 
                                    isOn=false });

        lstView.ItemsSource = listRelays;

    }

    private void OnChanged_2(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedItem = ((SwitchCell)sender).BindingContext as 
          Relays;

        if (true)
        {            
            bool IsToggled = e.Value;
            string name = IsToggled.ToString();

            if (name == "True")
            {
                //DisplayAlert("ON", "Relay 1 On", "Cancel");
                BackgroundColor = Color.Silver;

                //Set the switch Property to ON state (toggled)
                selectedItem.isOn = true;

                //Check if the switch has been toggled and change the 
                   states accordingly
                if (selectedItem.isOn == true)
                {
                    BackgroundColor = Color.Gold;

                }
            }

            else
            {
                //DisplayAlert("OFF", "Relay 1 OFF", "Cancel");
                BackgroundColor = Color.LightSkyBlue;
            }

        }

    }// OnChanged event       

}// partial class

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be following the MVVM pattern so, I will give you a basic run through:

First, your Relays class should be your binding context so that the properties there would be accessible to your XAML file which can be set in two ways

- Through Xaml something like this :

  ```
  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
  <local:Relays/>
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>
  ```

Where local is the namespace of your class and Relays is your class name.

- Through C# something like this :

  ```
   public RelayControl()
  {
   InitializeComponent ();
   loadSampleData();
   this.BindingContext=new Relays();
  }
  ```

Now in your ListView Do the Following Changes :

```
 <ListView x:Name="lstView" SelectionMode="None">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <SwitchCell x:Name="Sw1" Text="{Binding Name, 
                 Mode=TwoWay}" On="{Binding BindingContext.isOn,Source={x:Reference lstView}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                            OnChanged="OnChanged_2"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
```

After that, it should work like a charm

In case of issues revert

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will give it a try shortly.

Comment: How would I create the variable to access the Name property of the SwitchCell with the above method implemented?

Comment: What exactly do you plan on doing with the name property? Do you want to use it to get the Switch cell object? Because you cannot get a reference of a view that is in an itemtemplate

Comment: So I can't, for example, change the Name when the SwitchCell state changes?

Comment: No you cannot change the name like that but the actual data in it can be changed

Comment: How would I do that? is there no way of saying, for example, var x = lstView.BindingContext as Relays; and then x.Name="New"?

Comment: How can I change the state of the SwitchCell **isOn** property in _listRelays.Add(new Relays { Name ="Relay 1", State = "", isOn= RelayOn });_ by using the binding? Or is there a different way that I need to do that? I currently have a **var neg = lstView.BindingContext as Relays;** and **RelayName = neg.Name;** in the **public RelayControl()** above, i then want to check the state the switch is in or alter it in this RelayControl.xaml.cs class with **RelayName**. Is this not possible ? How would I achieve this if not ?